Reusable React Hook Form Zod-validated input field using ShadCN Form component
I built a reusable email input field that looks as follows:
import { UseFormReturn } from 'react-hook-form';

import { TEmailSchema } from '@/schemas/authentication';
import { FormField, FormItem, FormLabel, FormControl, FormMessage } from '@/components/ui/form';

import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input';

export default function EmailInput({ form }: { form: UseFormReturn<TEmailSchema> }) {
  return (
    <FormField
      control={form.control}
      name="email"
      render={({ field }) => (
        <FormItem>
          <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
          <FormControl>
            <Input placeholder="john@doe.com" {...field} />
          </FormControl>
          <FormMessage />
        </FormItem>
      )}
    />
  );
}

And also built a reusable password input field that looks as follows:
import { UseFormReturn } from 'react-hook-form';

import { TPasswordSchema } from '@/schemas/authentication';
import { FormField, FormItem, FormLabel, FormControl, FormMessage } from '@/components/ui/form';

import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input';

export default function PasswordInput({ form }: { form: UseFormReturn<TPasswordSchema> }) {
  return (
    <div className="mb-1">
      <FormField
        control={form.control}
        name="password"
        render={({ field }) => (
          <FormItem>
            <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
            <FormControl>
              <Input type="password" {...field} />
            </FormControl>
            <FormMessage />
          </FormItem>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

It uses the following two independent Zod schemas.
import * as z from 'zod';

export const EmailSchema = z.object({
  email: z.string().min(1, { message: 'Email address is required' }).email('Value must be an email address')
});

export const PasswordSchema = z.object({ password: z.string().min(1, { message: 'Password is required' }) });

I want to use these email and password components individually at times, and at other times together, depending on the form. This is why each field has its own independent schema. For example, on a login form I'd like to be able to compose both inputs like this somehow.
import React from 'react';
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from 'react-hook-form';

import { EmailSchema, type TEmailSchema, PasswordSchema, type TPasswordSchema } from '@/schemas/authentication';
import { Form } from '@/components/ui/form';

import EmailInput from '../../_components/email-input';
import PasswordInput from '../../_components/password-input';

export default function LoginForm() {
  const form = useForm<TEmailSchema & TPasswordSchema>({
    resolver: zodResolver(EmailSchema.and(PasswordSchema)),
    defaultValues: {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  });

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<TEmailSchema & TPasswordSchema> = async (data) => {
    console.log('Fields passed validation: ', data);
  };

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="w-full">
        <div className="mb-10">
          <EmailInput form={form} />
        </div>

        <div className="mb-10">
          <PasswordInput form={form} />
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Log in</button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
}

The problem, of course, is that the types of the form between the login form and the individual email and password inputs don't match. So form={form} fails Typescript check. The email input expects a form of type TEmailSchema, password input expects a form of type TPasswordSchema, but the actual composed form under which both inputs live is of type TEmailSchema & TPasswordSchema.
Is there a way to solve this without resorting to copying and pasting the code inside EmailInput and PasswordInput into every page where I use <Form {...form}> that needs one or both of these inputs? I feel there should be a way to do this, and I've spent far too much time and have hit a brick wall.
Note #1: @/components/ui/form is the uncustomized ShadCN UI form component.
Note #2: I thought of creating these two additional forms in the login form component:
  const emailForm = useForm<TEmailSchema>({
    resolver: zodResolver(EmailSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: ''
    }
  });

  const passwordForm = useForm<TPasswordSchema>({
    resolver: zodResolver(PasswordSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      password: ''
    }
  });

and passing them to the respective "form" prop for the email and password input components as such:
    import React from 'react';
    import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';
    import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from 'react-hook-form';
    
    import { EmailSchema, type TEmailSchema, PasswordSchema, type TPasswordSchema } from '@/schemas/authentication';
    import { Form } from '@/components/ui/form';
    
    import EmailInput from '../../_components/email-input';
    import PasswordInput from '../../_components/password-input';
    
    export default function LoginForm() {
      const form = useForm<TEmailSchema & TPasswordSchema>({
        resolver: zodResolver(EmailSchema.and(PasswordSchema)),
        defaultValues: {
          email: '',
          password: ''
        }
      });

  const emailForm = useForm<TEmailSchema>({
    resolver: zodResolver(EmailSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: ''
    }
  });

  const passwordForm = useForm<TPasswordSchema>({
    resolver: zodResolver(PasswordSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      password: ''
    }
  });
    
      const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<TEmailSchema & TPasswordSchema> = async (data) => {
        console.log('Fields passed validation: ', data);
      };
    
      return (
        <Form {...form}>
          <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="w-full">
            <div className="mb-10">
              <EmailInput form={emailForm} />
            </div>
    
            <div className="mb-10">
              <PasswordInput form={passwordForm} />
            </div>
    
            <button type="submit">Log in</button>
          </form>
        </Form>
      );
    }

This solves the type mismatch for the email and password "form" prop, but the validation of the Form itself does not work properly because the inputs being validated are associated with a different form from the form being "submitted". So a solution continues to evade me.
